# PrepareForSegue called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am calling the following method in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[self unreadMessageCounter];
}
```

In that method I am getting a value with parameter name "MsgCount". For that the written code is.

```
-(void) unreadMessageCounter{
NSUserDefaults *defaultUser=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString* username = [defaultUser objectForKey:KUserName];
NSString* password = [defaultUser objectForKey:KPassword];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..."       maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
});

NSString *url3 ;
NSString *base_url=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     objectForKey:@"BASE_URL"];
url3=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@%@?    username=%@&password=%@&deviceUniqueId=%@",base_url,MESSAGE_COUNTER,username,password,[defaultUser objectForKey:KDeviceToken]];
[defaultUser synchronize];


NSURL *requestURL =  [NSURL URLWithString:[url3 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:requestURL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)urlResponse;
    NSLog(@"Response Code For Message Counter:: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
    if(response){
        NSMutableDictionary *returneDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Return Dict For Message Counter:: %@", returneDict);

        if (returneDict != nil) {
            if ([returneDict valueForKey:@"valueSet"]){
                for (NSDictionary *dict in [returneDict valueForKey:@"valueList"]) {
                    _counterNumber = dict[@"MsgCount"];
                    NSLog(@"counter number %@", _counterNumber);
                }
            }
            else{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            });
        }
    }
}];
[task resume];
```

}

After that I am passing that _counterNumber string to the next view controller with the help of prepareForSegue, for that the following code is.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

if (![segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Notification"]) {
    UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
    WelcomeScreenViewController *welcomeScreenViewController =     (WelcomeScreenViewController *)nav.topViewController;
    welcomeScreenViewController.counterString = _counterNumber;
  }
}
```

It was going to the next view controller but on the first call, after didselectrowatindexpath instead of unreadMessageCounter method, prepareForSegue is getting call that's why the _counterNumber value I am getting nil, but on the second time when I am calling then It is working as usual. So plese help me in that case because I am not getting any clue.

Comment: Where you have call perform segue?

Comment: is this mandatory to call perform segue?

Comment: Show your storyboard scene

Comment: Just made segue from one controller to another controller and perform your segue with identifier whenever you feel.

Comment: I have written in my code that     ' if (![segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Notification"]) {
    UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
    WelcomeScreenViewController *welcomeScreenViewController =     (WelcomeScreenViewController *)nav.topViewController;
    welcomeScreenViewController.counterString = _counterNumber;
  }
}'

Comment: I am checking ! in this

Comment: check once you directly conected the segue to your vc

Comment: Yes, i know you are checking and it done good, but you must made segue from cell to next VC that is why it perform without any code. You need to connect segue from VC to VC.

Answer (score 1):

First Disconnect your `segue` from cell to `nextViewController`. And make new segue from current ViewController to your `nextViewController` like below screenshot [image]

And after processing you API that you are calling in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` perform segue through code like below.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Show Notification" sender: self];
```